# unnumbered lines in LyX algorithm float

Tags: lyx, algorithms, line-numbering

I'm trying to write an algorithm in LyX, and since I'm a hebrew user a lot of methods did not work for me.

I tried the following method, which worked but doesn't have numbered lines. I'd like to know how I can automatically add line numbers to the algorithms.

The method I'm using for writing algorithms is Clicking Insert->Float->Algorithm, writing the name of the algorithm at the top red box, and simply writing (plain text + math environemnts) the algorithm in the big red box (and switching the format from "Standard" to "LyX-Code").

Thanks in advance!

Here is an example Lyx file, with a screenshot of the output pdf:

[image]

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass heb-article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{culmus}
%\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}
%\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\floatname{algorithm}{אלגוריתם}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-starred
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing double
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 1.5cm
\topmargin 1.5cm
\rightmargin 1.5cm
\bottommargin 1.5cm
\secnumdepth -2
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation skip
\defskip medskip
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Float algorithm
placement H
wide false
sideways false
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
אלגוריתם מבחן
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code

\series bold
\lang english
if 
\begin_inset Formula $n==1$
\end_inset

 then:
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset


\begin_inset Formula $\quad$
\end_inset

return 2
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code

\series bold
\lang english
return 3
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Does Insert > Program Listing do what you need?

Comment: @scottkosty I inserted a Program Listing and typed in a few random lines, didn't get any line numbers, I also can't use math mode inside

Comment: RIght click on the program listing and go to "Settings", and there is a "Line numbering" setting. But indeed, I do not think it is meant to include math so might not be what you're looking for.